# Button out of 3 graphic parts with fluid mid-part

Tags: css

I have an image:

[image]

with 3 parts:

[image], [image] and [image]

I want a button with a repeating part2, so the button text (centered) is variable.
But the button text should range 50% into the other pieces.

Part1 and part3 need a min width I think, unfortunately I have no useful example.

`:before` and `:after` didn't work very well (with `position:absolute` or similar), because the repeat part have to be fluid between the outer parts.

Any ideas? Greetz.

Comment: Many years ago there was some technique called [sliding door](http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors), also https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/ , demo page https://css-tricks.com/examples/Sprites+SlidingDoors-Button/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modern posibility would be using border-image.

But if you want a wider support, do it with backgrounds. 
The problem is that a repeating bkg is difficult to size . So, it's best to handle it in a pseudo element

```css
.test {
 min-width: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 90px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 0px 20px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: white;
 background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/mYxcX.png'), url('//i.stack.imgur.com/TlpN0.png');
 background-size: auto 100%;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left top, right top;
 position: relative;
}

.test:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/GMhMi.png');
 background-size: auto 100%;
    left: 90px;
    right: 100px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">long test</div>
<div class="test">much longer test</div>
```

And the same, using border image. Using this image

[image: sample]

we will get this: (note the trick about height:0px to allow for a single image in all the left and right sides.)

```css
.test {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 20px;
 height: 0px;
 font-size: 30px;
 border-width: 50px;
 border-image-source: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXiA6.png);
 border-image-slice: 50% 49% 50% 50% fill;
 border-image-repeat: repeat repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">TEST</div>
<div class="test">long test</div>
<div class="test">much longer test</div>
```

Comment: Nice and unique solution too, you're right about `border-image` I've never used it before but seems it could be implemented. UpVoted.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, very nice solution.

Comment: I added a z-index to the main class, without that some browser settings will cause problems.

Comment: Well spotted ! And happy that it helped you

Comment: This `border-image` is handy, easy and doesn't need much work and effort to get it done.. some answers on S.O I wish I can double upvote it.. Kudos

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED and *totally Changed***:

Thanks to [@vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals) comment below which let me had the "idea bulb" above my head, *hence the* "*unless*.." *part in the comment*.

This new solution is much cleaner in CSS and HTML, less code, no need to worry about `position:absolute`, no need for extra mess, just simply uses "multiple backgrounds" <sup>(1)</sup> as well as `calc()`<sup>(2)</sup> function with `min-width` too techniques. but first here's the code and comments will explain:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/7a8u04k5/)

```css
.test-class {
  /* so that div can expand to contain the text as well as the padding */
  width:auto;
  
  /* min width = 173px left image width + 199px right image width */
  /* without this it'll collapse */
  min-width:372px;
  
  padding:0 20px 0 10px; /* just to give it breathign space on sides */
  line-height: 148px;
  color: white;
  font-size:24px;
  
  /* no color background because the images are PNGs with alpha */
  background-color: transparent;
  
  /* setting multiple images having the middle "extendable" one as third background */
  background-image: url('//i.stack.imgur.com/mYxcX.png'),
                    url('//i.stack.imgur.com/TlpN0.png'),
                    url('//i.stack.imgur.com/GMhMi.png');
  
  /* set no repeat to all, even the extendable otherwise it'll appear behind the
     other two images, instead we don't repeat it but control its size later */
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
  
  /* position each image to its corresponding position, the 46.5% for the middle 
     image is because the left-side image has less width than the one on the right */
  background-position:left center, right center, 46.5% 50%;
  
  /* finally giving the images on the sides their exact-pixel size, while for the
     one on the middle we make use of calc() function, so the width size of the middle
     image = full div size (100%) - the width values of the left and right image (173+199) */
  background-size: 173px 148px, 199px 148px, calc(100% - 372px) 148px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-class">Home</div>
<div class="test-class" style="margin-left:200px;">about company</div>
<div class="test-class">example dummy text for demo only</div>
```

---

Alternatively, as I commented, you can use the [CSS Sliding Door](http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors) technique which was so practical and used a lot before CSS `border-radius` and CSS shadow presented and simplified interfaces. another example [perfect CSS sprite sliding doors button](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/perfect-css-sprite-sliding-doors-button/)

This [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/w6bxzn1v/) shows how to implement the sliding door method for achieving such task, while it looks kind too much wide for this images set, since the right side image has `199px` width, it could be used for images with less width values.

And this [**JS Fiddle 3**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/aLgopcve/) is similar to sliding door but with `:before` and `:after` but with one issue that it has to have `display:block` which make it not workign for horizontal alignment but could be fixed with javascript after settign it's `display` to `inline-block`.

Also there's another way, using SVG as background image which is better first because it is scale-able especially for non linear images like the blue ink circle used in the great example by [@vals](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1926369/vals) .

Second benefit of using SVG is using inline SVG and because SVG is made of groups and element could be targeted with CSS just like targeting other DOM elements.

https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

### ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

<sup>(1)</sup>. Resources:

- [caniuse - Multiple backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds)
- [MDN - Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

(2). Resources:

- [caniuse CSS calc()](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc)
- [MDN - calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)
- [CSS-Tricks - A couple of use cases for calc](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/)

Comment: A great answer. But I think that the OP wanted the text to extend into the pseudo elements

Comment: If so then IMHO I don't think it is do-able in CSS only, but with javascript it could be done.. unless..

Comment: Again, a great answer :-) And in a single background, not an easy thing !